# Magento 1.9.0 Magento Connect Manager displays 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect-manager, downloader

We are using Godaddy server, The server displayed this:

[image: Server displayed error message]

Comment: Please add file https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php on your magento root and run

Comment: There are many possible reasons for "Internal Server Error". It's usually a PHP Fatal Error or a misconfiguration in `.htaccess`. Check your server error logs to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

yes, i got it.

change the permissions

1. Open control panel select downloader folder. "**downloader**" *folder is 755.*
2. File **downloader/index.php**. "*index.php" file is 644*.
3. Refresh the **control panel** and **website admin**, then displayed magento connect manager admin panel
4. please replace downloader folder with fresh magento downloader folder.
5. just delete the cache in var folder.this will work perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy is know to keep having issue with default landing page as index.php
Try this on your url below:

```
http://yourdomain.com/downloader/index.php?return=http://yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/
```

Kindly replace your `yourdomain.com` with the correct domain of yours.

I hope this help. Dont forget to mark this as correct if it helps.